# ModalPopUpExtender Does not Work With DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, modalpopupextender

I have the MPE, mpeNew inside an Updatepanel, with a button btnClose inside.
It should show up with the selectedIndexChange event of few dropdownlists on page.

**C#:**

```
protected void ddlCustomer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(ddlCustomer.SelectedIndex==1)
   {
     ViewState["sender"] = sender; //MPE shows up only when this line's commented
     mpeNew.show();
   }
}

protected void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   mpeNew.Hide();
   DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)ViewState["sender"];
   ddl.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

The Modal shows up only when the viewstate declaration is commented. But It is acctually needed to know which dropdown opened the Modal. 
Also tried using this dropdown as a trigger in updatepanel.
There is no error. The modal just wont pop.
Where am I going wrong. Or is there any other way to get what I want.

Comment: Try enabling the javascript errors and debugging on the browser to see if there is a client side error happening.

Comment: `Uncaught  PagerequestManagerServerErrorException. Error serializing value system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist of type system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist` Is this the cause. Whats this about. How to fix?

Comment: I have answered your question based on your comment, the error is happening because DDL is not marked as serilizable, so it can not be stored in a ViewState.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropdown control is not serializable so when tring to store it in the viewstate the code breaks. Instead of saving the sender it would be more appropriate to save the ID of the dropdown in the ViewState. By the ID you can always find the control usin `FindControl("Id")` function. Exaple based on your code:

```
ViewState["sender"] = ddlControl.ID;

DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)FindControl(ViewState["sender"]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That did not work. I tried - `DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)FindControl(ViewState["sender"].ToString());` ddl is null .

Comment: If the dropdown is inside any panel then try e.g. Panel1.FincControl(ViewState["sender"].ToString()). I think the would work.

Comment: I have seen another question from you where you mentioned you have DropDown and Button on different pages. In that case this would not work. This is for the single page.